# Heat template: How to pass all the value in a dynamic map to the heat template

Tags: bash, templates, dictionary, user-data, heat

If I have a list, for example, `list1={"node1": "test1", "node2": "test2", ...}`(this list1 is not static, it is dynamic, the users can define its length), is there a way that I can pass ALL the value in the list1 into the bash script? Thank you very much.

Comment: This is JSON DATA, anda a mappign (dictionary), not a list. First you should check if you really want to deal with this in a bash script, or a more consistent language such as Python, Javascript or Ruby. (for all of which this kind of data is parsed in a transparent way)

Comment: Thank you very much. you are right this is a mapping not a list. I'd like to use python to parse it as follows:
for k in list1:
    print "list1[%s]= " %  k, list1[k]

Answer (score 0):

Try at least using a proper language to parse the data in there.

```
./my_script.sh `python3  -c "import sys; from ast import literal_eval; print(' '.join('--{} {}'.format(key, value) for key, value in literal_eval(sys.argv[1].split('=')[-1]).items())"`
```